# obfuscate strings and important tokens even after decompile app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have some important token in my app and in typical build , everyone can read my token after decompile app file. There are any way to hide my tokens?

I'm using kotlin
My target sdk is 33

Also I tried minify but the result it's not enough.

Comment: This question has been asked quite a few times but there is no 100% protection of secrets in an app. You can only make it a bit harder. For protecting apps there are a lot of commercial protectors available. In general you get what you pay for which means that all free solutions are next to useless.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the token for ? As an local api key or as an credential to the server? If its used locally then you can only make it harder to attracted like storing it separately and assemble it on runtime in native code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to hide most of api or special string in android

we can use ndk in android and hide strings on c++ files and after compile it's convert to `.so` file's

for first step see this repository:

https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/hello-jniCallback

It's better to convert your string to `base64` and then reverse it and finaly put it on c++ files
and you can call it every where and then first revers it and decode `base64`

```
// stringFromJNI coming from c++ file's
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellojniMsg)).setText(stringFromJNI());
.
.
.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hello-jnicallback");
}
public native  String stringFromJNI();
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem with the issue is that either the information required to decrypt your data is available without your presence, or it is not.

If it is, it's there for anybody who looks in the right place.

If it's not you have to be standing next to every one of your users when they fire up the app.

Comment: Thank you sir,
But i think we have to hard and hard and hard the way to reach data by users. every harder it's better. any one can't say it's way is 100 % trust

Comment: Have you considered encrypting it and having something like a 2fa server back at your office that hands out keys that are good for a nonce?

More or less requiring some kind of human interaction to keep the data unlocked ...